# Roots of sum of a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

Suppose I have the following polynomials:

\begin{align}
a(x) &= a_0+a_1x + a_2x^2 + \cdots a_nx^n \\
b(x) &= b_0+b_1x + b_2x^2 + \cdots b_nx^n \\ 
c(x) &= c_0+c_1x + c_2x^2 + \cdots c_nx^n 
\end{align}

where all of the coefficients for $a(x)$, $b(x)$, and $c(x)$ are real. The roots of these polynomials can be complex or real. Now suppose it is stated that the roots of the function:

$f(x) = a(x)b(x) + c(x)$

have negative real parts. Additionally, the roots of $a(x)$ and $c(x)$ also have negative real parts. Can any conclusions be made on the roots of $b(x)$?

Note: We are not given the actual values of the coefficients of the above polynomials.

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks!